# How do you enable FTS in Xcode for an iOS app?

Tags: ios, xcode, full-text-search

I would like to enable FTS in an iOS app. Do I need to include the SQLite binaries, or is there a CFLAG or something I can add to enable it? Do I have to include the amalgamation source?

Answer (score 6):

I discovered that FTS is already included in the sqlite framework included in Xcode.  To enable it, do the following:

1) First, include the `libsqlite3.dylib` framework to your project.

2) Then add the following CFLAGS:

`-DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3_PARENTHESIS`
`-DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3`

For what its worth, FTS4 works as well, just change the CFLAGS to:

`-DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS4_PARENTHESIS`
`-DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS4`

Comment: You no longer need to include these flags to access FTS anymore. FTS just works out of the box in iOS as long as you include the libqlite3 library.